# Some cases I can't see return value from print()

Tags: python, django, printf

I asked question similar to this issue.
[I can't see return value from print() located in some class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49937038/i-cant-see-return-value-from-print-located-in-some-class)
But I still didn't understand the reason of this question.

When I run django server, following index method must be called.

```
def index(request):
    print("fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff")
    print("request",request)
    return render(request, 'personal/home.html')
```

Then, I will see home.html on the web browser.
It means index() is called, right?
But I can't see return value from  `print("fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff")` and `print("request",request)` on terminal window, when I run command `$python manage.py runserver`

Please, let me know the reason why this happens, how to see return value.

---

1st edited

This is mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', include('personal.urls')),
]
```

This is mysite/personal/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')]
```

Requst url on the browser: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

---

I found the answer for this question.
As soon as, run this command,

```
$python manage.py runserver
```

I couldn't see return value from print().

But when I send any requests like refresh page, click some links on the page, I could see return value from print() on the terminal console.

Comment: please post your urls.py and the url you asked to see home.html

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add `$` (which indicate end of string) at the end of pattern if you are using `include`. Change base `urls.py` to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('personal.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I tried to remove "$" at point you mentioned.
It worked fine at both cases(with $ and without $)
But I found question for this case.